# Appeneded HTML via jQuery wont take the click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This behavior has blocked me last few days. I have the `waypoint` jQuery plugin installed and it loads more comments when the bottom of the page is reached. The loaded HTML include some buttons with classes that must be triggered on click **via jQuery** as well. This is not working.

So this scenario sums it up pretty well:

- The comments loaded *with the document* have their **like, dislike and delete** buttons working
- User reaches the bottom of the page and jQuery loads more comments to the page via an AJAX call
- The **like, dislike and delete** that came from the AJAXed comments do not trigger on events.

Why? I don't get it. They have the correct classes and everything.

The HTML:

```
<div class="comments">
    <div id="new-comment"></div>

    <script>var commenters = [{{ S_IMAGE_COMMENTERS }}];</script>

    {% for comment in S_IMAGE_COMMENTS %}
        <div id="cid-{{ comment.comment_id }}" class="comments-area row{% if loop.last %} last-comment{% endif %}">
            <div class="user-info col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 right">
                <img src="{{ comment.user_avatar }}" height="75px" alt="Avatar" class="comment-avatar valign-top img-circle cream-thick-border" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1" style="width: 2%;"></div>
            <div class="comment-rag col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 left" style="padding: 0;">
                <div class="comment-content row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 break">
                        <span class="small comment-stats">
                            Posted by <strong><a href="{{ S_WEB_PATH }}user/{{ comment.username }}">{{ comment.username }}</a></strong> about {{ comment.comment_time }}
                            <span class="grey">
                                &nbsp;/&nbsp;<span class="clikesCount">{{ comment.comment_likes }}</span> likes
                                &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;<span class="cdislikesCount">{{ comment.comment_dislikes }}</span> dislikes
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="pipe-hide">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="comment-options">
                            <button value="{{ S_IMAGE_NAME }}?do=comment{% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'like' %}un{% endif %}like" class="likeUnlike"><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"{% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'like' %} style="color: #aa4e4e;"{% endif %} title="{% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'like' %}Unlike{% else %}Like{% endif %}"></span></button>

                            <button value="{{ S_IMAGE_NAME }}?do={% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'dislike' %}remove_{% endif %}commentdislike" class="dislikeUnlike"><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"{% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'dislike' %} style="color: #aa4e4e;"{% endif %} title="{% if comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid and comment.like_type != '' and comment.like_type == 'dislike' %}Remove Dislike{% else %}Dislike{% endif %}"></span></button>
                            {% if comment.commenter_id != S_USER_ID %}<button><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" title="Report"></span></button>{% endif %}

                            {% if comment.commenter_id == S_USER_ID %}<button value="{{ S_IMAGE_NAME }}?do=delete_comment" class="deleteComment comment-option close" title="Delete">&times;</button>{% endif %}

                        </span>

                        <span class="comment-content-main break">{{ comment.comment_content }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr{% if loop.last %} style="display: none"{% endif %} class="line-{{ comment.comment_id }}" />
    {% else %}
        <div class="row noComments">
            <br />
            <div class="col-lg-12 center">
                <h3><span>There are no comments for this image.</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- .comments -->
```

The jQuery (responsible for loading more comments):

```
    // Load more comments when bottom's reached
    var $loading    = $('<div class="loading row" style="display: none;"><div class="col-lg-12 center">' + generate_preloader(32, 3) + '</div></div>');
    var $footer     = $('.last-comment');
    var $docURL     = document.URL;
    var $imageName  = $docURL.substring(-5);
    var $start      = { from: 10 };
    var opts        = { offset: '100%' };

    //alert($imageName);

    $footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {

        var $commentCount = document.getElementsByClassName('comments-area');

        if ($commentCount.length < 10)
        {
            return; 
        }

        $footer.waypoint('destroy');
        $('.loadMore').append($loading);
        $('.loading').fadeIn('slow');

        delay('comments', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $imageName + '?do=fetchMoreComments&start=' + $start.from,
                success: function(data){

                    // console.log(data); return;
                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                    if ('error' in response)
                    {
                        $loading.fadeOut('fast');
                        return;
                    }

                    $start.from += 10;
                    $loading.detach();
                    $footer.waypoint(opts);

                    // Remove previous last class
                    $('.comments-area').removeClass('last-comment');

                    var commentsLength = response.comments.length - 1;

                    for (var key in response.comments) 
                    {
                        var comment = response.comments[key];

                        var commentHTML = ((key == 0) ? '<hr />' : '') + '<div id="cid-' + comment.comment_id + '" class="comments-area row' + ((commentsLength == key) ? ' last-comment' : '') + '" style="display: none;">';
                        commentHTML += '<div class="user-info col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 right">';
                        commentHTML += '<img src="' + comment.user_avatar + '" height="75px" alt="Avatar" class="comment-avatar valign-top img-circle cream-thick-border" />';
                        commentHTML += '</div>';
                        commentHTML += '<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1" style="width: 2%;"></div>';
                        commentHTML += '<div class="comment-rag col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 left" style="padding: 0;">';
                        commentHTML += '<div class="comment-content row">';
                        commentHTML += '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 break">';
                        commentHTML += '<span class="small comment-stats">';
                        commentHTML += 'Posted by <strong><a href="' + generate_site_url() + 'user/' + comment.username + '">' + comment.username + '</a></strong>';
                        commentHTML += '<span class="grey">';
                        commentHTML += '&nbsp;/&nbsp;<span class="clikesCount">' + comment.comment_likes + '</span> likes';
                        commentHTML += '&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;<span class="cdislikesCount">' + comment.comment_dislikes + '</span> dislikes';
                        commentHTML += '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + comment.comment_time;
                        commentHTML += '</span>';
                        commentHTML += '</span>';
                        commentHTML += '<span class="pipe-hide">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>';
                        commentHTML += '<span class="comment-options">';

                        commentHTML += '<button value="' + $imageName + '?do=comment' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'like') ? 'un' : '') + 'like" class="likeUnlike"><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'like') ? ' style="color: #aa4e4e;"' : '') + ' title data-original-title="' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'like') ? 'Unlike' : 'Like') + '"></span></button>';

                        commentHTML += '<button value="' + $imageName + '?do=' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'dislike') ? 'remove_' : '') + 'commentdislike" class="dislikeUnlike"><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'dislike') ? ' style="color: #aa4e4e;"' : '') + ' title data-original-title="' + ((comment.comment_id == comment.liked_cid && comment.like_type != '' && comment.like_type == 'dislike') ? 'Remove Dislike' : 'Dislike') + '"></span></button>';

                        // commentHTML += '<span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>';
                        commentHTML += (comment.username != $('.user-username').text()) ? '<button><span class="comment-option glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" title="Report"></span></button>' : '';
                        commentHTML += (comment.username == $('.user-username').text()) ? '<button class="comment-option close" title="Delete">&times;</button>' : '';
                        commentHTML += '</span>';
                        commentHTML += '<span class="comment-content-main break">' + comment.comment_content + '</span>';
                        commentHTML += '</div>';
                        commentHTML += '</div>';
                        commentHTML += '</div>';
                        commentHTML += '</div>';
                        commentHTML += '<hr' + ((commentsLength == key) ? ' style="display:none"' : '') + ' />';

                        $('.comments').append($(commentHTML));
                        $('.comments-area').slideDown('fast');
                    }
                }
            });
        }, average_ajax_delay);

    }, opts);
```

The jQuery that triggers the **like, dislike and delete button**:

```
// Comment like, dislike, unlike and remove dislike
    $('.likeUnlike').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var likeHref  = $(this).val();
        var commentID = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').substring(4);

        var likeUnlike   = (likeHref.indexOf('commentunlike') != -1) ? 'commentunlike' : 'commentlike';
        var oppositePreg = (likeUnlike == 'commentlike') ? 'commentunlike' : 'commentlike';

        var likeStr =  (likeUnlike == 'commentlike') ? 'Unlike' : 'Like';

        var likeUnlikeUrl   = likeHref.replace(/comment(un)?like/g, oppositePreg);
        var thumbColor      = (likeUnlike == 'commentlike') ? '#aa4e4e' : '#A2A2A2';

        $(this).val(likeUnlikeUrl);
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .glyphicon-thumbs-up').attr('data-original-title', ucfirst(likeStr));
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .comment-options .tooltip-inner').text(ucfirst(likeStr));
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .comment-options .glyphicon-thumbs-up').css('color', thumbColor);

        // Check if dislike is clicked
        dislikeButton = $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .dislikeUnlike');
        if (dislikeButton.val().indexOf('remove_commentdislike') != -1)
        {
            dislikeButton.val(dislikeButton.val().replace(/(remove_)?commentdislike/g, 'commentdislike'))
            dislikeButton.children().attr('data-original-title', 'Dislike');
            dislikeButton.children().css('color', '#A2A2A2');
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: likeHref,
            data: { commentID: commentID },
            success: function(data){

                // console.log(data); return;
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                if ('error' in response)
                {
                    display_alert(response.error, 'danger', 3000, 'top');   
                    // return;
                }

                $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .small.comment-stats .grey .clikesCount').replaceWith(response.clikeCount);
                $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .small.comment-stats .grey .cdislikesCount').replaceWith(response.cdislikeCount);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('.dislikeUnlike').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var dislikeHref = $(this).val();
        var commentID   = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').substring(4);

        var dislikeUnlike   = (dislikeHref.indexOf('remove_commentdislike') != -1) ? 'remove_commentdislike' : 'commentdislike';
        var oppositePreg    = (dislikeUnlike == 'commentdislike') ? 'remove_commentdislike' : 'commentdislike';

        var dislikeStr  =  (dislikeUnlike == 'commentdislike') ? 'Remove Dislike' : 'Dislike';

        var dislikeUnlikeUrl    = dislikeHref.replace(/(remove_)?commentdislike/g, oppositePreg);
        var thumbColor          = (dislikeUnlike == 'commentdislike') ? '#aa4e4e' : '#A2A2A2';

        $(this).val(dislikeUnlikeUrl);
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .glyphicon-thumbs-down').attr('data-original-title', ucfirst(dislikeStr));
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .comment-options .tooltip-inner').text(ucfirst(dislikeStr));
        $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .comment-options .glyphicon-thumbs-down').css('color', thumbColor);

        // Check if dislike is clicked
        likeButton = $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .likeUnlike');
        if (likeButton.val().indexOf('unlike') != -1)
        {
            likeButton.val(likeButton.val().replace(/comment(un)?like/g, 'commentlike'))
            likeButton.children().attr('data-original-title', 'Like');
            likeButton.children().css('color', '#A2A2A2');
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dislikeHref,
            data: { commentID: commentID },
            success: function(data){

                // console.log(data); return;
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                if ('error' in response)
                {
                    display_alert(response.error, 'danger', 3000, 'top');   
                    // return;
                }

                $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .small.comment-stats .grey .clikesCount').replaceWith(response.clikeCount);
                $('#cid-' + commentID + ' .small.comment-stats .grey .cdislikesCount').replaceWith(response.cdislikeCount);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('.deleteComment').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var deleteHref = $(this).val();
        var commentID  = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').substring(4);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: deleteHref,
            data: { commentID: commentID },
            success: function(data){

                // console.log(data); return;
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                if ('error' in response)
                {
                    display_alert(response.error, 'danger', 3000, 'top');   
                    return;
                }

                $('#cid-' + commentID).slideUp('fast');
                $('.line-' + commentID).slideUp('fast');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

So, as said, the HTML loaded with the document (when the page loads for the first time) has the like, dislike and delete button working normally. However, when new comments come from the AJAX, those button don't work.

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Search for *event delegation*. There is plenty of question on this subject that can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to bind the events using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding event to dynamically added elements which are not present at the time `event` binding code gets executed. You can delegate event to `static` parent of the dynamically added elements or to document.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteComment', function(e){

});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Or you can use the function [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for better readability i guess.